# WebFlowTestCase registerFlow() multiple flows possible?

Tags: integration-testing, spring-webflow

Hi I have a WebFlowTestCase and is working fine but I ran into a prob when I need to test another flow that is in the same controller ( groovy). 
The is what my controller looks like:

```
        class MyController {

    def someService
    def dateHelper = new DateHelper()
    def index = {... }
    def myCreateFlow = {
              start{}
              createCase{}
              finishCancel{
    }
    def myViewFlow = {...}
    def myEditFlow = {...}
    }
```

I have managed to successfully create the test for **myCreateFlow** like this:

```
  class MyControllerTest  extends WebFlowTestCase {

        def myController =  new MyController();

        @Override
        public Object getFlow() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             return myController.myCreateFlow
        }
        protected void setUp() {
            super.setUp()
        }

        protected void tearDown() {
            super.tearDown()
        }

        void testmyCreateFlow()
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

my question is how about the myEditFlow and myViewFlow? How do I register or use it when the getFlow() returns only the myCreateFlow? Is there I way I can use all of them in one webflowtest with out creating a new webflowtestclass? Or is there a way I can put it inside getflow with some switch/if else method something like:

```
@Override
            public Object getFlow() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if condition
                            return myController.myCreateFlow
                         else return myController.myEditFlow
            }
```

coz when i tried creating a testmyEditFlow() I get the error below and I know that it is because the get flow only returns the myCreateFlow. At least that is how I perceive the test error msg.

> Cannot find state with id 'myEditFlow' in flow 'test' -- Known state
>   ids are 'array['start', 'createCase'... 'finishCancel']'

Answer (score 0):

You could register your other flows in a setUp method as follows:

```
 protected void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    registerFlow("myController/myEdit", myController.myEditFlow)
    registerFlow("myController/myView", myController.myViewFlow)
}
```